# Cake PHP 2.10 inner join on model retrieving data missing?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a project that's written in Cake PHP 2. I have a model, which by nature uses the `belongsTo` association to pull in another model, but when I do my query, I need to be able to do an inner join of some sort on a third model.

I can't seem to find any mention of inner joins in the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), am I missing something?

My query looks like:

```php
$this->MyModel->find('all', array(
  'order' => array(
    'MyModel.hops' => 'desc'
  )
));
```

`MyModel` contains the `MyModel` and the belonging model, example: `MyModel2` as an array, but I need to now inner join a third model here since the ID of this third model.

Comment: **https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables**

Comment: I missed that part, thanks, but doesn't entirely answer my original question, my model, `$this->MyModel->find('all')` has a `$belongsTo` association to another model, e.g: `MyModel2` and is an Array inside of the returned data, I need to use this model in the conditions for the join, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking, how exactly is the PHP level result format relevant for your SQL queries?

Comment: I'll open a new question for this since it goes slightly beyond the scope then of this question.

Comment: If you're interested for some more context, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469597/cake-php-2-10-not-joining-linked-models-table-on-another-table-with-inner-join)